# how to change amount type to number type to perform arithmetic operations in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, number-formatting

In javascript val is of amount type like $1,056.89. Now i want val to be performed with arithmetic operations but alert gives me as NaN instead of arithmetic value. if i take off Number then y value is as 1,056.8910 .how can i make val to numeric type and perform arithmetic operations?

```
var val= document.getElementById('<%= DataItemValue4.ClientID%>').firstChild.nodeValue;
            val= val.replace(/^[\s$]+|[\s]+$/g, '');
            y = Number(val)+ 10;
            alert(y);
```

can any one help me out with this !

thanking you, michaeld

Comment: Take the comma out of the string

Comment: i have given like this but comma is not vomited val= val.replace(/^[\s,]+|[\s]+,/g, '');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all non numeric characters and coerce the string to a number:

```
val = + val.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

After you strip out any non-numeric characters, try using [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) to convert the value to a floating point number.

```
val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
y = parseFloat(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should get things working -

```
var val= '$1,056.89';
val= val.replace(/^[\s$]+|[\s]+$|,/g, '');
y = parseFloat(val)+ 10;
alert(y);
```